# Desktop scrolls up and down

Tags: windows-7, scroll, desktop

I've got a computer running Windows 7 using a wide screen monitor, but whenever the mouse is moved to the top or bottom of the screen everything (including the icons and task bar) seems to scroll up or down off the screen.  I've looked through the control panel settings but can't find anything to turn this desktop scrolling feature off.  How do we disable this in Windows 7?

Comment: Unless you want to write a program to handle this issue, this is not a question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  The problem was fixed by changing the screen resolution to one that matched a wider screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the zoom feature on? If so you should turn it off.